# Adding include path value to .htaccess causes internal server error

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, include-path

Running on Linux & when I put this line into my .htaccess file I get an internal server error; what is wrong with it?

```
php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/php5/lib/php/PEAR:/usr/share/pear:/home/username/public_html/includes:.."
```

Comment: What does your error log say? Does apache have permission to all these folders, including `..`?

Comment: Seems it was cause the server was using suPHP for the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was using suPHP as the handler & that handler doesn't support setting php values via the .htaccess file; they have to be set via the php.ini file.